# XPATH Needed from HTML Markup

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have the below HTML Markup and I would like to extract a value out of it. I am using HTML Agility pack based on this article, but cannot figure out what will the XPath be for my need. I need to get from 2,85,877 **`<li class="BdrBt">2,85,877</li>`**
http://olussier.net/2010/03/30/easily-parse-html-documents-in-csharp/

```
<div class="Sellersdetail">

          <p>Below are the recommended valuations for Individuals & Dealers, on the basis of car condition.</p>
          <ul>
            <li class="Name MarginR20">
              <ul>
                <li>&nbsp;</li>
                <li class="BdrBt">Fair</li>
                <li class="BdrBt Text16 Good">Good</li>
                <li class="BdrBt">Excellent</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="Dealer MarginR15">

              <ul>
                <li class="First">Dealer</li>
                <li class="BdrBt">2,35,628</li>
                <li class="BdrBt Good">2,53,275</li>
                <li class="BdrBt">2,69,064</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="Individual">
                <ul>
                <li class="First">Individual</li>
                <li class="BdrBt">2,50,351</li>
                <li class="BdrBt Good">2,69,101</li>
                <li class="BdrBt">2,85,877</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
```

Comment: what have you tried..show us your attempt so that we can correct you..Also your question seems to be unclear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me. But since I don't have the entire html-page you will probably have to modify it.

```
//li[@class='Individual']/ul/li[last()]
```